# Chemfig "Missing { inserted" error

Tags: chemfig

I have been trying to draw a chemistry diagram using the following code:

```
    \schemestart
{\scriptsize \chemfig{
H-[:30]C(-[:90]H)(-[:-90]H)-[:-30]\Lewis{2:,N}(-[:-90]H)-[:30]C(-[:90]H)(-[:-90]H)-[:-30]C(-[:90]H)(-[:-90]N\rlap{${}^+$}(-[:-150]H)(-[:-90]H)-[:-30]H)-[:30]C(=[:90]\Lewis{1:3:,O})-[:-30]\Lewis{1:5:7:,O}^\rlap{${}^-$}
}}
\arrow{<=>}
{\scriptsize \chemfig{
H-[:30]C(-[:90]H)(-[:-90]H)-[:-30]N\rlap{${}^+$}(-[:-90]H)(-[:90]H)-[:30]C(-[:90]H)(-[:-90]H)-[:-30]C(-[:90]H)(-[:-90]N(-[:-150]H)-[:-30]H)-[:30]C(=[:90]\Lewis{1:3:,O})-[:-30]\Lewis{1:5:7:,O}\rlap{${}^-$}
}}
\arrow{<=>[$+$\chemfig{H^+}]}
{\scriptsize \chemfig{
H-[:30]C(-[:90]H)(-[:-90]H)-[:-30]N\rlap{${}^+$}(-[:-90]H)(-[:90]H)-[:30]C(-[:90]H)(-[:-90]H)-[:-30]C(-[:90]H)(-[:-90]N\rlap{${}^+$}(-[:-150]H)(-[:-90]H)-[:-30]H)-[:30]C(=[:90]\Lewis{1:3:,O})-[:-30]\Lewis{1:5:7:,O}\rlap{${}^-$}
}}
\schemestop
```

Unfortunately the following error comes
`! Missing { inserted.<to be read again>\hbox {`
`! Missing { inserted.<inserted text>{`
The error is attached to the second molecule, that is the line where `{\scriptsize \chemfig{` appears for the second time. How do I fix this error?

Comment: The issue is the `^\rlap{${}^-$}` at the end of the first `chemfig`. What precisely do you want to achieve with it?

Comment: The bonds will treat the whole `\Lewis{1:5:7:,O}^-` as one 'box'. See the chemfig documentation (https://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/CTAN/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf) and page 42 section 12.2

Comment: Yes, but what you have now yields an error, which disappears once you remove `^\rlap{${}^-$}`. So I am asking to understand what it is good for to be able with an alternative way to achieve the same.

Comment: The nitrogens and the oxygens are off centre in the atom as the whole N^+ or O^- section is treated as one 'atom', whereas I only want the N or the O part to be treated as the 'atom' so it is in line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just had an excess `^` in front of `\rlap`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\schemestart
{\scriptsize \chemfig{
H-[:30]C(-[:90]H)(-[:-90]H)-[:-30]\Lewis{2:,N}(-[:-90]H)-[:30]C(-[:90]H)(-[:-90]H)-[:-30]C(-[:90]H)(-[:-90]N\rlap{${}^+$}(-[:-150]H)(-[:-90]H)-[:-30]H)-[:30]C(=[:90]\Lewis{1:3:,O})-[:-30]\Lewis{1:5:7:,O}\rlap{${}^-$}
}}
\arrow{<=>}
{\scriptsize \chemfig{
H-[:30]C(-[:90]H)(-[:-90]H)-[:-30]N\rlap{${}^+$}(-[:-90]H)(-[:90]H)-[:30]C(-[:90]H)(-[:-90]H)-[:-30]C(-[:90]H)(-[:-90]N(-[:-150]H)-[:-30]H)-[:30]C(=[:90]\Lewis{1:3:,O})-[:-30]\Lewis{1:5:7:,O}\rlap{${}^-$}
}}
\arrow{<=>[$+$\chemfig{H^+}]}
{\scriptsize \chemfig{
H-[:30]C(-[:90]H)(-[:-90]H)-[:-30]N\rlap{${}^+$}(-[:-90]H)(-[:90]H)-[:30]C(-[:90]H)(-[:-90]H)-[:-30]C(-[:90]H)(-[:-90]N\rlap{${}^+$}(-[:-150]H)(-[:-90]H)-[:-30]H)-[:30]C(=[:90]\Lewis{1:3:,O})-[:-30]\Lewis{1:5:7:,O}\rlap{${}^-$}
}}
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]